# Select the elements of a specific form when many forms?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<form id="myform">

    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="2" />

<select name="var3" onchange="submitForm();return false">
<option value="1">choice 1</option>
<option value="2">chocie 2</option>
<option value="3">choice 3</option>
</select>       

</form>


<form id="myform2">

    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="2" />

<select name="var3" onchange="submitForm();return false">
<option value="1">choice 1</option>
<option value="2">chocie 2</option>
<option value="3">choice 3</option>
</select>       

</form>
```

[... etc with many forms]

and this JS:

```
        <script>
function submitForm() {
    var OAjax, var1 = document.getElementsByName('var1')[0].value,
        var2 = document.getElementsByName('var2')[0].value,
        var3 = document.getElementsByName('var3')[0].value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) OAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) OAjax = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    OAjax.open('POST', "return.php", true);
    OAjax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (OAjax.readyState == 4 && OAjax.status == 200) {
            if (document.getElementById) {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = '' + OAjax.responseText + '';
            }
        }
    }
    OAjax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    //create a parma string using the input values
    OAjax.send('var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2 + '&var3=' + var3);
}
        </script>
```

I want to get the variables from the form that the users is actually manipulating. But with the actual JS it doesn't select the values from the good form as they are many of them on my page. I'm trying to find a way to deal with many forms.

For example I tried `var1 = document.getElementsById('myform').getElementsByName('var1')[0].value,`
but it won't work

Should I maybe specify the id attribute value of the current `<form>` with `submitForm("myform")` for example ? If so what is the JS I need for interpreting this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to proceed. Here's a simple update that is only slightly different from what you have:

Change the call to submitForm to include the form ID, e.g.:

```
<select name="var3" onchange="submitForm('myform');return false">
```

Then use that in submitform:

```
function submitForm(formId) {
var OAjax,
    elements = document.getElementById(formId).elements,
    var1 = elements['var1'].value,
    var2 = elements['var2'].value,
    var3 = elements['var3'].value;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) OAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (window.ActiveXObject) OAjax = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
OAjax.open('POST', "return.php", true);
OAjax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (OAjax.readyState == 4 && OAjax.status == 200) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = '' + OAjax.responseText + '';
        }
    }
}
OAjax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//create a parma string using the input values
OAjax.send('var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2 + '&var3=' + var3);
```

}